# Create directory structure if it doesn't exist in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a directory structure if it doesn't exist in another location.  It works, but I get an error on any directory with a bracket in the name. I assume I have to escape that somehow, but don't know how.

Script code:

```
$source = "c:\data"
$destination = "c:\scrap\data"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
  ForEach-Object {
    if (!(Test-Path -path $_ )) { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ }
  }
```

Comment: "It works, but I get an error."  Does that mean it works *besdies* the places where there is an error, or that even bracket directories work fine, there is just error text written?  If the latter, just add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the cmdlet which is throwing the un-useful error.

Comment: Works for me without an error. What is the error you're getting? Please add the output of `$error[0].exception.tostring()` to your post.

Comment: If a directory with a bracket in the name already exists, it tries to create it again and I get an error:
  

`New-Item : Item with specified name C:\scrap\data\Evernote\backup\Untitled note [2]_files already exists.
At C:\data\PowerShell\Untitled5.ps1:9 char:67
+     ForEach-Object {if (!(Test-Path -path $_ )) { $null = New-Item <<<<  -ItemType Container -Path $_ }}
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\scrap\data\E... note [2]_files:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`

Comment: Weird. This shouldn't be happening, since you check with `Test-Path` before trying to create the directory. What do you get when you manually run `Test-Path` and `New-Item` with the path that raises the error?

Comment: Test-Path -path "C:\scrap\data\Evernote\backup\Untitled note [2]_files"   return false...which is not right. It does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. The error is due to the square brackets. They're used for pattern matches (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx)), so `Test-Path` actually checks for

> C:\scrap\data\Evernote\backup\Untitled note 2_files

which doesn't exist. You have to use `-LiteralPath` to avoid this.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a shorter solution:

```
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Filter {$_.PSIsContainer} -Recurse -Force
```